# Swift code cannot see method declared in Objective-C category

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode10, objective-c-category

I have a very simple Swift `objc` class from which I want to call a method that is defined in a category of a class defined in Objective-C.

However, the compiler is not happy:

```
.../UploadOperation.swift:25:24: error: value of type 'MyServer' has no member 'clearPendingData'
        self.server?.clearPendingData();
```

When I move the declaration of `clearPendingData` to the main class declaration, the compiler is happy (except I now get warnings in my Objective-C code about the main class vs category method implementations).

Here is the Swift declaration, in file UploadOperation.swift

```
@objc class UploadOperation: Operation {

    @objc var server: MyServer? = nil

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.completionBlock = { [unowned self] () in
            self.server?.clearPendingData()
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the category, in file MyServer+upload.h:

```
#import "MyServer.h"

@class UploadOperation;

@interface MyServer (upload)
    - (void) clearPendingData;
@end
```

And the main class declaration, in file MyServer.h

```
@interface MyServer : NSObject
    - (MyServer *) init;
    // and a ton of stuff omitted
@end
```

(of course, a lot of irrelevant code omitted)

This is with Xcode 10.1.

What gives?
Thanks

Comment: Have you included `MyServer+upload.h` in your bridging header as well as `MyServer.h`?

Comment: I hadn't. And that solves it. Duh! You might want to make that an answer so that I select it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to access Objective-C methods from Swift defined in a category you must included the category header as well as the class header in your bridging file. In this case include `MyServer+upload.h` as well as `MyServer.h`. Your error suggests you haven't done this. HTH